# Prove that there is no uniqueness of factorisation in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$.

Tags: number-theory, factoring, residue-calculus, pell-type-equations

Consider $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}] = \{x + \sqrt{10}y; x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

We want to show that there is no uniqueness of factorisation.

I think that it's better to consider $9 = 3 \cdot 3 = (\sqrt{10}-1)(\sqrt{10}+1)$. But now we need to show that $3$ and $\sqrt{10}-1$ are irreducibles in this ring.

There is a problem with this. My attempt : let's say $3 = (a+\sqrt{10}b)(c+\sqrt{10}d) = \sqrt{10}(ad + bc) + (ac +10bd)$, now we have that

$ad + bc = 0$ , hence $3 = (a-\sqrt{10}b)(c-\sqrt{10}d)$ is appropriate too. So we have that $9 = (a^2 - 10 b^2)(c^2 - 10d^3)$ which give us 4 possibilities : $9 = 1 \cdot 9 = (-1)\cdot(-9) = 3 \cdot 3 = (-3) \cdot (-3)$. It's easy to see that the las two cases are invalid.

But what about first scenario. There will be some solutions for $a^2 - 10b^2 = 1$ and $c^2 - 10d^2 = 9$, but how can I show that these solutions doesn't hold equation $ad + bc = 0$? Any hints?

Comment: If $9 = 3\cdot 3 = (\sqrt{10}-1)(\sqrt{10}+1)$ is *really* going to prove that this is not a UFD, then you **cannot** show that $3$ and $\sqrt{10}\pm 1$ are *prime*. Recall that $p$ is a prime if and only if it is not a unit and whenever $p|xy$, you must have $p|x$ and $p|y$. If this were a factorization into *primes*, then it would be unique. What you need to show is that they are **irreducible**, not that they are prime.

Comment: If $a^2-10b=1$, then $(a+\sqrt{10}b)(a-\sqrt{10}b) = 1$, so $a+\sqrt{10}b$ is a unit.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin i need to show that there is no uniqueness of prime factorisation

Comment: No, you need to show that there is no uniqueness of factorization into **irreducibles**.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I want to show that Fundamental theorem of arithmetics doesnt hold.

Comment: Yes, and that's about factorization into **irreducibles**. You need to keep the distinction between "prime" and "irreducible" straight. An element $p$ is **prime** if and only if it is not a unit, and whenever $p|xy$, either $p|x$ or $p|y$. An element $m$ is **irreducible** if it is not a unit, not zero, and whenever $m=xy$, either $x$ is a unit or $y$ is a unit. They are *not* the same concept in general.

Comment: Unique factorization says that every element can be written as a product of irreducibles, and that this product is unique up to order and associates. From this one can deduce that every irreducible is prime (in general, nonzero prime implies irreducible but not conversely).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin okay, I understand. So the main idea is $a + b\sqrt{10}$ is $1$ in this ring?

Comment: No, it's not $1$ in that ring. It's a **unit** (**if** $a^2-10b^2=1$).